# Can't assign to read-only property vba

Tags: excel, vba

Getting a "Compile error: Can't assign to read-only property" for the following:

```
With wsData.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill

    .Pattern = xlGrid
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End With
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Try `.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255,0,0)`

Comment: Thanks David. However I am still getting this error-  "Compile error:     Can't assign to read-only property".

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `ShapeRange` property in the middle:

```
With wsData.Shapes("Rectangle 1").ShapeRange
```

Full Code:

```
With wsData.Shapes("Rectangle 1").ShapeRange
    With .Fill
        .Pattern = xlGrid
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End With
```

---

**Edit 1**: Code with possible error handling

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorChape()

Dim wsData      As Worksheet
Dim myShp       As Shape

Set wsData = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify to your sheet's name

On Error Resume Next
Set myShp = wsData.Shapes("Rectangle 1")
On Error GoTo 0

If myShp Is Nothing Then ' <-- unable to set the shape, doesn't exist in specified sheet
    MsgBox "`Rectangle 1` Shape doesn't exist in " & wsData.Name & " sheet!", vbCritical
Else
    With myShp
        With .Fill
            .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ' rest of your code goes here

        End With
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the reply. No that didn't work either.

Comment: @ajdesanti are you sure you have a `"Rectangle 1"` Shape ? in `wsData` worksheet ?

Comment: The error is occurring because of  ".Pattern = xlGrid" because the code works fine when I run this-                                                                 With wsData.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill
                
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
             
                                        
         End With